# Is it mandatory to add security group to catalog in Azure? are there any other ways?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm creating access packages. I would like to know, Is it mandatory to add security group to catalog 1st then add those security groups to access package?

I'm bit unclear about "resource roles" [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-create)

However,lets say, If I add them directly to the access package ( during access package creation) like below:

> " Add resource roles" -> "group and teams" -> select check box which
> says (See all groups and teams not in the "catalog-name" catalog. You
> must have correct permissions to add them in this access package) ->
> then search the security group -> Select the security group to add.

[image: Screenshot for above mentioned steps for reference]

What could be the problem? Will it have some problematic consequences? If yes, what would be the consequences? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to add security group to catalog 1st then add those
> security groups to access package

It is not mandatory to add security group to catalog first and then add those security groups to access package

As you are selecting check box which says See all groups and teams not in the "catalog-name" catalog, **these groups will be added to the catalog** for the other catalog administrators to build access packages with

Comment: Hi @RamaraoAdapa-MT, thanks for your response. - Will there be any security related issues? if I select the check box and then search and then add...  Just wanted to make sure I'm following best practice  and there must not be any problem going forword.

Comment: There will not be any security related issue if you select the check box and then add the security groups.